# insert "Assignment Operator Expression" to complete Expression

Tags: java

I am using Java and I have the error 
insert "Assignment Operator Expression" to complete Expression"

what is the meaning of this error?.
Is there a List of all java error Messages and what they mean?

thanks

Comment: I think it is easier to post the relevant code here and get an answer :)

Comment: Your code is probably incorrect.  Perhaps you could post the line which was incorrect we could tell you why. I tried googling your error message and it could not find a match. Can you check this is the real error message?

Comment: @Peter, try googling for *insert assignment operator expression to complete expression* I always remove all punctuation characters to be sure it's no "special" search. Google will favour results in which the words come close to each other anyway. I also, Remove Capitalization Etc... I've read (a long time ago) that if you use mixed case, google assumes you know for sure how the case should be.

Comment: @aioobe, good tips on using google.

Comment: Sorry I have no code now. I will try later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this page](http://cnx.org/content/m31181/latest/) you're doing this

> - Writing an assignment statement without the assignment operator:
>
>   ```
>   max ;          // Error, missing =
>   ```
>
>   Eclipse: **Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression"   to complete Expression**

You should know though that the compile error messages are implementation dependent. The above applies for the Eclipse compiler. Suns `javac` would for instance say

```
YourFile.java:line: not a statement
max ;
^
```