# Eclipse extract to method not working for Lambdas

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, lambda

I'm playing around with lambdas in eclipse oxygen. I have code something like this

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface TriFinction<O,I,J, R> {
    R whatEver(O object, I input1, J input2);
}

class Dummy {
    public String dothingsWithTwoArgs(String a, String b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}

public class LambdaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dummy::dothingsWithTwoArgs;
    }
}
```

I'm unable to extract Dummy::dothingsWithTwoArgs. Eclipse is showing a compilation error **Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression**, but extraction is working perfectly in intellij. Is there any workaround for this in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

First notice that your **dothingsWithTwoArgs** is not static, therefore you should not attempt to invoke it in a static fashion: you should use an instance of your Dummy class or make the **dothingsWithTwoArgs** static

Here are some illustrations that will get you going

First you need a method that has your TriFinction as one of its parameters

Example:

```
public static String sumToString(String a,String b, String c, TriFinction<String,String,String,String> f) {
        return f.whatEver(a, b, c);
    }
```

Second, in your Dummy class **you need a method that matches the genric signature of your TriFinction** (which means for example that it receives three parameters for O,J, and I and that it returns a R)

for example

```
public static String dothingsWithThreeArgs(String a, String b,String c) {
            return a+ " " + b + " " + c;
      }
```

Now you can use the method reference in your main method for example:

```
System.out.println(sumToString("2","3","4",Dummy::dothingsWithThreeArgs));
```

Here is the full example along with a second illustration from your TriFinction (and I guess you should refactor and rename it TriFunction :) )

```
public class ExtractWithLambda {
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface TriFinction<O,I,J, R> {
        R whatEver(O object, I input1, J input2);
    }   

    public static String writeEqu(TriFinction<Double,Double,Double,String> f) {
          return f.whatEver(2.5, 3.4, 5.6);
    }

    public static String sumToString(String a,String b, String c, TriFinction<String,String,String,String> f) {
        return f.whatEver(a, b, c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(writeEqu(Dummy::writeEquation)); 
        System.out.println(sumToString("2","3","4",Dummy::dothingsWithThreeArgs));
    }

}

class Dummy {
      public static String dothingsWithThreeArgs(String a, String b,String c) {
            return a+ " " + b + " " + c;
      }

      public static String writeEquation(double a, double b, double c) {
            return a + "*x*x " + b + "*x " + c ;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not expecting code to be working. I just need to know why eclipse didn't extract that to a variable. When I did ctrl+shift+l in intellij, it extracted that to "TriFinction<Dummy, String, String, String> dothingsWithTwoArgs = Dummy::dothingsWithTwoArgs;". I think method reference also works for non static methods. For example String::toLowerCase

Answer (score 0):

One main thing we should know is ***Compilation error messages are compiler dependent***. This does ***not*** mean different compilers would produce different error messages ***all the time***. But there can be situations.

Regarding your problem I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4468986/5715934) and [post](http://cnx.org/contents/Teawjwe-@1/Syntax-Errors-in-Java). That post has a detailed explanation about this error under topic ***not a statement***.

So the main point is this. As you mentioned, this error message is ***specific*** to ***Eclipse compiler***. The point the compiler is raising is your line is just an ***expression***, ***not a statement***. In order to understand it as a statement, the compiler wants you to ***add an assignment*** operator. That's the whole meaning of  `insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression`. So what you all want to do is just assign that line to another defined variable, which would look like this.

```
someVariable = Dummy::dothingsWithTwoArgs;
```

Hope you can find more depth and more examples with the sources I mentioned. :))

Answer (score 0):

Extracting Lambda to a method seems only suported from Eclipse 4.23 (Feb. 2022, 6 years later)

> ### [Extract lambda body to method](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.23/jdt.php#extract-lambda-body-to-method)
>
> A new content assist has been added to extract the body of a lambda to a method.
> To invoke the new feature, perform a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> within the selected lambda body:

[image: class -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.23/images/extract-lambda-body-to-method.png]